# Office 365 shared calendar all events not appearing

Tags: calendar, office365, outlook-web-access

I have added another user to an existing shared calendar in the Outlook Web App on Office 365. The calendar has appeared for the new user but they can only see a very small number of the events on it.

There is nothing in common between the events that appear that I can see. Some events are Free; some are Busy. Some have one category; some have another.

I've tried removing the user from the calendar and re-adding them and they get the same result. The user has *Can Edit* permissions.

Comment: Do any other users also have access to this calendar? Can they see all events?

Comment: Yeah. There are around 10 with can edit and 40+ with view details. I've added users after this one with no problems. It's just this one user who can't see everything.

Comment: Has this user tried multiple browsers? Is there anything different about the way their email account is set up, compared to everyone else?

Comment: Checked back with the user today and after no input from me the problem appears to have sorted itself. Not sure what was going on there.